# QR code URL has illegal '%03', can I HTTP redirect?

Tags: iis, html-encode

There is a printed QR code with '%03' (line break) accidentally encoded into URL. Is it possible to use HTTP Redirect to point invalid URL to a new web folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is "no". Browsers will not process the %03 so the HTTP request never makes it to the server.